# Reading files with double double quotes in R

Tags: r, data.table, readr

I am reading a few thousand csv files where some columns have a very 'interesting' format: `{""Q0"":""double double quote""}`

It seems `read.csv` reads it fine, but both `read_csv` and `fread` are doing different things (see below). My expectation would be to have: `{"Q0":"double double quote"}`

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```r
# Content of csv file
# "numbers", "simple_quote", "double_quote"
# "9", "quoted text", "{""Q0"":""double double quote""}"

library(readr)  
library(data.table)
  
read.csv("test.csv")
#>   numbers simple_quote                  double_quote
#> 1       9  quoted text  {"Q0":"double double quote"}

read_csv("test.csv")
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   numbers simple_quote double_quote                      
#>     <dbl> <chr>        <chr>                             
#> 1       9 quoted text  "{\"Q0\":\"double double quote\"}"

fread("test.csv")
#>    numbers simple_quote                     double_quote
#> 1:       9  quoted text {""Q0"":""double double quote""}
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Do you want to keep the double quotes in the resulting string? Or do you want to save the characters that we within the double quotes?

Comment: `read_csv` is actually returning basically the the same data as `read.csv` if you strip the whitespace after the comma: `read.csv("quotes.txt")$double_quote[1] == readr::read_csv("quotes.txt")$double_quote[1]`. I'm not sure which value you think is "correct" in this case. There are a lot of weird CSV files out there. There's on open issue at data.table for this difference: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4779

Comment: Thanks for your answers! My expectation is to get: `{"Q0":"double double quote"}`.

Comment: I suggest that since `read.csv` and `readr::read_csv` are doing it correctly, and `data.table::fread` has a known bug with this, then the quick answer to your question is: **Yes, this is a bug**. I can think of no easy workaround to continue using `fread` (in R or shell-scripting), so I don't know if this question can be shifted into *"how to use `fread` here"*, I think you're stuck using one of the other two for now. (Until https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1109 and github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4779 are resolved, that is. Note that `#1109` was filed in 2015.)

Comment: Thanks r2evans. The speed benefit of fread makes it 'unavoidable' in this case, so I opted for taking care of the double double quotes with gsub().

Comment: @Gorka Could you please show your workaround using `gsub()` as an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to consolidate @MrFlick and @r2evans  comments in a single response, and include my final workaround as @jens-piegsa suggested.

It seems to be a bug, at least on the data.table front:

- https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1109
- https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4779

In my use case, the speed advantage of data.table is huge, so I added a gsub() step to take care of the double quotes.

```
DF %>% mutate(stimulus = gsub('\\{""Q0"":""|""\\}', '', stimulus))
```